# How can I use Remote Desktop to connect to another user on the same computer?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vps

I have a VPS running the 64-bit version of Windows 7.

The VPS has several users. When using the VPS, I sometimes want to use Remote Desktop to connect to another user. To attempt to do this, I initiate a RDP session to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). This fails with the error: "The client could not connect. You are already connected to the console of this computer. A new console session cannot be established."

How can I fix this error?

I can connect to other VPS servers running the same OS.

Comment: When you're connecting from one to the other, are you just opening RDP and going from there or are you using the mstsc /admin commands. 

Reason I ask is because the "You are already connected to the console of this computer" raises a red flag in that you're connected and then attempting to reconnect back to the console.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to the other user, are you trying to see what they see while they are logged in or do you just want to "be" the other user so any actions you perform are in the context of the other user. The way you solve the problem is different depending on what you want to do.

Comment: for question  one: yes i just open RDP and type 127.0.0.1 and user name and press connect, and type password of that username.

Comment: for question  one: yes i just open RDP and type 127.0.0.1 and user name and press connect, and type password of that username. for question two, i have running a process and when i cloze RDP, it will be stop, but if  go to  user2 and there open RDP , and connect to user1 and run the process on user1 , and i just cloze my RDP , not user2, its don't be stoped.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the loopback IP address, meaning it's connecting back to the same computer. to find out your network address, type "ipconfig" into your command line (cmd) or check the properties of your network connection

Comment: yes, my gold is connect to same computer, even when i use network address in RDP , its show me the same error as when i use 127.0.0.1